# 2048 : Strange behaviour of reduceRight in map with lodash/fp

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, 2048

The following code is the beginning of an attempt to make my version of 2048 (the game) using lodash-**fp**. I'm used to regular lodash, but this is my first contact with the fp flavor.

It implements the action of pushing to the right the tiles of one row, using two functions:

- `slide` pushes the row to the right, provided there are empty spaces (represented by the value 0). In effect, this amounts to putting all the zeros on the left.
- `merge` merges pairs of contiguous tiles of same value, generating an empty space and a new tile of doubled value.
  (`slide` is called a second time after `merge` to clean up the zeros that may result from that step).

The functions use the `_.reduceRight` method, which iterates over the tiles from right to left.

```
import _ from "lodash/fp";


let game = [[2, 2, 0, 0], [4, 0, 4, 0], [8, 0, 0, 8], [16, 16, 0, 0]]; // Sample state

let slide = _.flow(
  _.reduceRight(
    (v, acc) =>
      v === 0 ? [_.concat(acc[0], v), acc[1]] : [acc[0], _.concat(v, acc[1])],
    [[], []]
  ),
  _.flatten
);

let merge = _.flow(
  _.reduceRight(
    (v, acc) => {
      acc[0].unshift(v);
      if (acc[0].length === 2) {
        if (acc[0][0] === acc[0][1]) {
          acc[1] = _.concat(0, _.concat(acc[0][0] + acc[0][1], acc[1]));
          acc[0] = [];
        } else {
          acc[1] = _.concat(acc[0].pop(), acc[1]);
        }
      }
      return acc;
    },
    [[], []]
  ),
  _.flatten
);

// Moves one line
let moveLine = _.flow(
  slide,
  merge,
  slide
);

// Moves the 4 lines
let moveBoard = _.map(moveLine);
```

`moveLine` seems to work well. For instance, `moveLine(game[0])` transforms `[2, 2, 0, 0]` into `[0, 0, 0, 4]`.

Strangely, `moveBoard(game)` (which maps `moveLine` over the 4 rows) gives a weird result, getting longer on each iteration, as though the results from the previous steps were appended:

```
[
  [0,0,0,4],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,8,4],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,8,4],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,16,8,4]
]
```

I see that the problem comes from `merge`, but I really fail to see what's going on here.

Comment: Please explain more about how slide and merge should work. Examples of the logic would be great.

Comment: To summarize the logic with one example:

Starting with: [8, 8, 2, 2],

`slide`: => [8, 8, 2, 2] (does nothing because there are no zeros)

`_.reduceRight` (steps from 3 to 0):
step 3 => [2][],
step 2 => [2,2][] => [][0, 4],
step 1 => [8][0, 4],
step 0 => [8, 8][0, 4] => [][0, 16, 0, 4] 

`_.flatten`: => [0, 16, 0, 4]

`slide`: => [0, 0, 16, 4]

Which is the expected outcome of the action of pushing the line to the right, as per the rules of 2048.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `move`  method to remove the first 4 elements.

for some weird reason for each iteration of `merge`

the acc[1] of ReduceRight as the previous array in it

this patch will fix it

```
let take = arr => arr.slice(0,4);

// Moves one line

let moveLine = _.flow(
  slide,
  merge,
  take
);
```

here is a runkit with the implementation

https://runkit.com/naor-tedgi/5ccf0862b0da69001a7db546

Answer (score 1):

I've opened a GitHub issue with a simplified version of the problem: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4287.

Short answer given by lodash creator John-David Dalton:

> With fp composition the accumulator is not create fresh for each composed reduce function. This is why create a mutationless version of the accumulator with fp.concat() works.